# How to get the suggestions in a the box after using the DOT symbol in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, content-assist, testng-eclipse

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

In this I am not getting the suggestion box option like `SLEEP` after putting the dot symbol, this is just one example like this I am not getting suggestion box where ever it should be display.

NOTE: I am getting this option only when I will be use `CTRL`+`Shift`+`space`

Comment: `sleep` is `void` method. What you want in that suggestion box (it called "auto complete")?

Comment: *only when I will be use CTRL+Shift+space* - Are you expecting it to be automatic?

Comment: From your question, it’s not clear, what you want. Can you add the html of the desired element and your attempt to achieve to get it?

Comment: Yes like earlier when i was using the dot symbol only (I was getting the options once i out the dot symbol)

Comment: Ex 1 - driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/"); -- autocomplete has to be come when use dot symbol after write the driver

Comment: check Menu `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist` The options for `Auto Activation` should be set as desired

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Java* and *Eclipse* to activate the suggestions you need to **activate** the **Content Assist** for **Auto Activation** as per the snapshot below browsing through: `Window` -> `Preference` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Content Assist` and set the *Auto Activation* options as per the snapshot:

[image: activate_Content Assist_AutoActivation]